# Minimizing Repition of Code using SAX in Java

Tags: sax, saxparser

```
class Foo {
    String member1;
    String member2;
    // Getters and Setters
    ...
}

class XmlDao extends Default Handler{
    List<Foo> foos;
    Foo tempFoo;
    String tempValue;
    ...

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ac, int i, int j) throws SAXException {
        tempValue = new String(ac, i, j);
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String s, String s1, String element) throws SAXException {
        ...
        if (element.equalsIgnoreCase("member1")) {
            tempFoo.setMember1(tmpValue);
        }
        if (element.equalsIgnoreCase("member2")) {
            tempFoo.setMember2(tmpValue);
        }
        ....
    }
}
```

The problem here is that for ever member variable that I add to the model Foo, I also have to go into the DAO and add the

```
        if (element.equalsIgnoreCase("member1")) {
            tempFoo.setMember1(tmpValue);
        }
```

to its `public void endElement`. I realize I can `switch` it but the problem is identical. What is the best way to handle this? Ideally I would rather write once in once class. After some searching on this problem I came across `Reflection`. This allows me to write twice, but in one class, as opposed to two classes:

In my model Foo I added the following static method:

```
public static Map<String, Method> getMap() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    Map<String, Method> map = new HashMap<String,Method>();
    map.put("member1", Foo.class.getMethod("setMember1", String.class));
    map.put("member2", Foo.class.getMethod("setMember2", String.class));
    return map;
```

}

In my XmlDao I added a `Map<String, Method> map`, and a call to `Foo.getMap()` in its constructor. I also got rid of the `if`/`switch` statements in the `endElement` method and added the following to that method:

```
for (Entry<String, Method> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (element.equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getKey())) {
        entry.getValue().invoke(tempFoo, tmpValue);
    }
}
```

So this method works but I still don't find it elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Why use the `for` in your solution ? Just do:

```
if (map.containsKey(element)) {
    map.get(element).invoke(tempFoo, tmpValue);
}
```